# Multiple Questions on Pivotal Cloud Cache

Tags: cloud-foundry

My Team and I are evaluating how to run our Software in Cloudfoundry. We already use Apache Geode in our Product so it would be nice to use Pivotal Cloud Cache. I have multiple Questions:

- Is it possible to install and use Pivotal Cloud Cache on any private Cloudfoundry installation (Pivotal Cloud Foundry and Open Source)?
- Is it under a specific licence or are there any licence costs for Pivotal Cloud Cache
- Is there a backup functionality for Cloud Cache to do backups  to an
  external file dump

Comment: This would not seem to be an appropriate question for StackOverflow as it is about installation of software, licensing of software, and operational use of that software. These would all seem to be questions to address to the actual software provider as they would seem to depend on what ever agreements you have in place or are considering.

Answer (score 0):

Pivotal Cloud Cache (PCC) is a separately licensed product from Pivotal CloudFoundry.  There's currently a per GB charge.

I think technically it could be installed on Open Source CloudFoundry, but this would need to be validated with Pivotal from a license perspective.  Also, Ops Manager is used to deploy components of PCC, so this might be a bit tricky.

I am attaching the link to PCC which details out the architecture to your last question.

https://docs.pivotal.io/p-cloud-cache/1-0/index.html#architecture

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned in a prior comment these are questions best answered by the vendor.  PCC is an opinionated deployment of GemFire for the PCF environment and is primarily configured via the Ops Manager tile. GemFire is the commercially supported version of Apache Geode.

You can get information and contact vendor about the product from the following link:

https://pivotal.io/platform/services-marketplace/data-management/pivotal-cloud-cache

and latest release documentation at which covers requirements and features:

https://docs.pivotal.io/p-cloud-cache/1-4/index.html